# I'm trying to Validate username and password

Tags: java, sql, validation, jdbc

I am trying to ensure that when a user enters username & password, authentication is done by checking if input matches some row in the user table. Here is the code so far: It doesn't respond when the login button is click. Please suggest how I can set it right. Thanks

```
 private void dbConnection()
{
   try
   {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maths_tutor", "root", "jesus");
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE username = '"+this.txtUser+"' AND password = '"+this.txtPass+"'";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(CHECK_USER);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String user = txtUser.getText();
            String pass = txtPass.getText();

            if(user.equals(rs.getString("username")))
            {
                if(pass.equals(rs.getString("password")))
                {
                    this.dispose();
                    new AboutTo().setVisible(true);
                }
                else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Password");
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password");
        }



       stmt.close();
       rs.close();
       conn.close();
   }


   catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException er)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + er.toString());
   }

}
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Why are you checking that the SQL for your database works?  If you get a result, there was a match, you don't need to check it. BTW If you don't get a match, it doesn't return a random record which doesn't match, it returns nothing so you should use `if(rs.next()) { ok } else { not ok }`

Comment: This piece of code just compares the given username and password with the DB data. Where is the code which calls this method on click of the login button?!

Comment: Did you try to debug the code when the login button is clicked. Check values for username and password there and see if the logic is correct.

Comment: First:- "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Password")" this piece of code is not required as your will only get resultSet if it satisfies both username and password either you can make two different statements where you check username and password separately. Second:- you have to first check if their is any response when you click button and then check whether database connectivity is working fine...

Answer (score 1):

```
String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE username = '"+this.txtUser+"' AND    password = '"+this.txtPass+"'";
```

you have passed username & password in sql query so it go in while block only if username And password will match ...

you supposed to make sql querylike this 
    String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records";

or you can use if block like this
    if(rs.next()
    {
    //login successfull code
    }
    else
    {
    //login fail
    }

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `getText()` on `txtUser` and `txtPass`.

This is how you could fix your query:

```
String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE username = '" + this.txtUser.getText() + "' AND password = '" + this.txtPass.getText() + "'";
```

You should note that concatenation of raw input text to queries will open vulnerability to SQL injection. You should use `PreparedStatement` instead so that the input text is properly escaped.

The following is a way to implement this properly, however lacks the following things that should be of concern to you:

- You are storing passwords in clear text. You should use a hashing function such as SHA-1.
- Every authentication will result in a new connection to the database. You should probably use a proper connection pool.

.

```
private boolean authenticate() throws SQLException {
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maths_tutor";

    // This query will simply count the matching rows, instead of actually selecting
    // them. This will result in less bandwidth between your application and the server
    String query = "SELECT count(*) AS num_records FROM records WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    // Obtaining the username and password beforehand could perhaps make it more clear
    // and prevent errors instead of pulling the data every time you need it
    String username = txtUser.getText();
    String password = txtPass.getText();

    // The try-with-resources block will make sure the resources are closed once we are done with
    // them. More information available at
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
    try (
        // Open database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "jesus");

        // Prepare the statement
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
    ) {
        // Set the username and password for the SQL statement
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        stmt.setString(2, password);

        // Execute the query in a try block, to ensure that the resources
        // will be released
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                // If we got 1 or more matches, this means we successfully
                // authenticated. Otherwise, we failed authentication.
                return rs.getInt("num_records") > 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Failed authentication.
    return false;
}

// Rename this to something meaningful according to your application
private void doAuthentication() {
    try {
        if (authenticate()) {
            // Do successful authentication handling
            this.dispose();
            new AboutTo().setVisible(true);
        } else {
            // Do failed authentication handling
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password");
        }
    } catch(SQLException er) {
        // Do error handling
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + er.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the logic is wrong.

What you are doing is approximately this.

1. Get a username and a password from the user.
2. Ask the database for all records for which the user name is matches the supplied username and the password matches the supplied password.
3. For each such record:

   1. Test if the user name matches, and open a dialog if it doesn't match.   **That won't happen ...** because you only selected records with that user name.
   2. Test if the password matches, and open a dialog if it doesn't match.   **That won't happen ...** because you only selected records with that password.

---

What you really ought to be doing is:

1. Get a username and a password from the user.
2. Select the records that match the user name and password.
3. Print a message if the *number* of records that you matched is zero.

---

I should also point out some other things:

- Popping up a dialog box to tell the user his user name / password are wrong is beside the point.  What you *really* need to do is tell something else in your server that the login failed.
- When the user gets just the username or just the password incorrect, you should not offer him *any* clues that one was correct.  Doing that makes it easier for "the bad guy" to work out the correct combination.
- Storing passwords in clear in a database is Bad Practice.  Best practice is to store seeded hashes of the passwords ... and use a cryptographically strong hashing function.

Answer (score 0):

The possible error would be near this line

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maths_tutor", "root", "jesus");
```

first make sure you have set the classpath and added the mysql driver to the project
second I would the following instead of the above, in fact why do you make things to much complex?!

```
java.sql.Driver _dr=new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
java.util.Properties _pr=new java.util.Properties();
_pr.setProperty("user","root");
_pr.setProperty("password","jesus");
Connection conn = _dr.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maths_tutor", _pr);
```

and the last thing is beware about using this like of code

```
String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE username = '"+this.txtUser+"' AND password = '"+this.txtPass+"'";
```

so here the system is ready for [injection](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/sql-server-t-sql-tips-tricks.html#tips).
so the good way would be like this, using parameters.

```
String CHECK_USER = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";//this will avoid sql injection
java.sql.PreparedStatement _st=conn.prepareStatement(CHECK_USER);
_st.setString(1, this.txtUser);
_st.setString(1, this.txtPass);
```

**EDIT :**
by the way, there is no need to iterate over result set! simple just call the `next()` method, if it returns true, so it means user has entered correct user/pass, else otherwise.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(CHECK_USER);
if(rs.next()){/*user exist*/
this.dispose();
new AboutTo().setVisible(true); }
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string query = "SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[login1] WHERE username='" + username.Text + "' and password='" + password.Text + "'";

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {MessageBox.Show("YEAH");}
```